# Java function to set unknown type of arraylist

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist

I want to be able to create ArrayList of unknown type in order to fill spinner
I have the following method, but I missed the correct syntax type..
I need to pass it the class type (for example "Person"), the spinner id and the array of the classes ("Person[]").

```
private void fillSpinner(Class clss, int id, Class[] c_array) {
    List<clss> list = new ArrayList<clss>();
    for (clss c : c_array) {
        list.add(c);
    }
}
```

the c_array type should be the type of clss.
for example - calling to this methos should be:

```
Person[] persons = ....
fillSpinner(Person, R.id.person_spinner, persons)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the method Generic and you don't need the first parameter:

```
private <T> void fillSpinner(int id, T[] array) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T t : array) {
        list.add(t);
    }
}
```

Then, you will be able to provide the Generic type for the method like this:

```
Person[] persons = ....
fillSpinner<Person>(R.id.person_spinner, persons)
```

Comment: please fix your typo `List<cT>` ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
private <T> void fillSpinner(int id, T[] c_array) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T c : c_array) {
        list.add(c);
    }
}
```